# What to use in finding frequency response : \$G(s) \cdot H(s) \$ or \$ \dfrac{G(s)}{1 + G(s) \cdot H(s)}\$?

Tags: control-system, transfer-function, bode-plot, frequency-response

While studying frequency response of control systems, all of the sources I'm referring to is considering unity feedback system i. e. H(s) = 1 & drawing Bode plots and polar plots on basis of that.

But what if feedback is not unity? Do I have to do analysis and Bode plot with

\$G(s) \cdot H(s)\$ or \$ \dfrac{G(s)}{1+G(s)\cdot H(s)} \$ ?

and why?

*Note : G(s) is forward path transfer function.*

I thought it should be

$$\dfrac{G(s)}{1+G(s)\cdot H(s)}$$
but one not-so-reliable source (tutorials point website) states that it has to be

$$G(s) \cdot H(s)$$

Also why \$G(s) \cdot H(s)\$ is called open loop transfer function?

Comment: Your question is unreadable. Add some line breaks to split it in to a few paragraphs.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie Sorry for that, I've edited it.

Comment: Have you seen: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed-loop_transfer_function  The closed-loop transfer function is derived in the same way weather H(s) = 1 or not. It is **not** that G(s)*H(s) is called open loop transfer, rather the open loop transfer of a system as in the Wiki page **is** G(s)*H(s). To understand this simply **cut** the loop, for example at the input of G(s). Then follow the signal from there to the other side of the cut, that makes G(s) * H(s). The open loop TF is usd for stability analysis so that is why it is important.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie OH I SEE! Thanks a lot for that info, but do I use OLTF for plotting Bode plot?

Comment: That depends on what you want to analyze. Do you want to plot the behavior of the whole system with working feedback **or** do you want to evaluate stability of the loop?

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie I want to evaluate stability of the loop.

Comment: Then you need to a make Bode plot of the OLTF.

Comment: Bode plot and Nyquist Diagram were proposed to determine the closed-loop stability by examining G(s)H(s) instead of 1+G(s)H(s). Sometimes G(s)H(s) can be regarded as "pseudo" open-loop transfer function. Discussions on ResearchGate question [Why is it that in a Bode plot realization we consider open loop transfer function as G(s)H(s)?](https://www.researchgate.net/post/Why_is_it_that_in_a_Bode_plot_realization_we_consider_open_loop_transfer_function_as_GsHs) provides more details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is the "open loop transfer function"?

To avoid misunderstandings and to be conform with the relevant literature, I like to clarify:

1) The "open loop transfer function" is the forward transfer function G(s) of the active device only without any feedback (when the loop is "open").

2.) The transfer function of the whole loop (but OPEN) is the so called "Loop gain" L(s)=G(s) * H(s).

3.) The transfer function of the whole circuit with feedback applied is

A(s)=G(s)/[1+ L(s)]

Note that this formula applies for negative feedback only. Otherwise the "+" sign has to be replaced by a "-" sign.

4.) For stability analyses, we only need the loop gain response L(s) in the BODE plot (magnitude and phase separated) or in the Nyquist plot (magnitude and phase combined).